# Toggle Shift for Single Keypress

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to turn my shift key into a CapsLock of sorts. The goal being that, when Shift is pressed, it shifts the next key to be pressed (eliminating the need to hold down the shift key), similar to the function of StickyKeys but only for the Shift key. I am able to toggle the Shift key using:

```
LShift:: Send % "{Blind}{LShift " . ((lshift:=!lshift) ? "Down}" : "Up}")
```

But that requires me to press Shift again, basically turning it into a CapsLock. How can I have this action only last for one keypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
$LShift:: 
    SendInput, {LShift Down}
    KeyWait, LShift
    SendInput, {LShift Down}
    Input, Key, L1 V
    SendInput, {LShift Up}
Return
```

edit:

```
$*LShift:: 
    SendInput, {LShift Down}
    Input, Key, L1 M V
    If GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
        KeyWait, LShift
    SendInput, {LShift Up}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works, but is there a way to detect if a key is pressed while Shift is held down and not shift the next key as well?

Comment: Hm, yes you could probably do that using `GetKeyState("LShift", "P")` which returns `True` if the key is physically held down.